# Git merge with data modified in one branch and nothing done in other branch

Tags: git, git-merge

If we merge two branches such that in one branch I edit the whole file from start to end and in other branches, I do not change anything left the original content then what will be the final content of the file when I merge both branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably *it depends*. It depends mostly on the shared parent of the 2 branches. And more things may get involved based on the merge strategy Git lands on.

The most likely answer will be:

- Git will check the common parent where the file is still present.
- Git will see that the file was deleted after branch created.
- Git will merge with the branches and leave the file deleted.